How to install and use webcam in Ubuntu 24.04 laptop?(Lenovo Ideaflex 14)
am new to Ubuntu. I installed Ubuntu on my Lenovo Ideaflex 14 laptop in place of Windows 10. But my webcam is not detected or I do not know how to activate the webcam, which was working under Windows 10. Appreciate any help. Thanks

you may find this article from itsFOSS of some help
